# I am trying to seed a database but having a problem with Sequelize: Failed to open the referenced table 'undefined'

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I get this error message in terminal: SequelizeDatabaseError: Failed to open the referenced table 'undefined'. The terminal message is not pointing to any of my files, so It is difficult to understand the source of it.

It looks that the problem is related to how the relationships are made between the tables.

My models are:

Users.js

```````js
    const {DataTypes, Model} = require('sequelize');
    const sequelize = require('../config/connection');
    const Message = require('./Message');

    class User extends Model {


    }

    User.init(
        {
            user_id:{type: DataTypes.INTEGER, primaryKey:true, notNull:true,},
            username:{type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false, unique:true},
            first_name:{type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false},
            last_name:{type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false},
            password:{type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false},
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            freezeTableName: true,
            modelName: 'User',
            underscored: true,
            timestamps: false,
        },
    );

    module.exports = User;
    ``````
    Message.js
    ``````lang-js
    const {DataTypes, Model} = require('sequelize');
    const sequelize = require('../config/connection');
    const User = require('./User');
    const Comment = require('./Comment');

    class Message extends Model {
    }

    Message.init(
        {
            message_id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                notNull: true,
                autoincrement: true,
                references: {model: Comment, key: 'message_id'}
            },
            content: {type: DataTypes.STRING},
            username: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull:false, references:         {model: User, key: 'user_id'}},
        },
        {
            sequelize,
            freezeTableName: true,
            modelName: 'Message',
            timestamps: false,
            underscored: true,
        }
    );

    module.exports = Message;
    ``````


What am I doing wrong?
```````

Comment: Did you create the seeds with the sequelize cli? ([seeds](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html#creating-the-first-seed)). That could be your problem. Once created you need to insert the data as an array in the generated bulkInsert() of the file.

Comment: I didn't. I typed the json file myself.

Comment: first of all, please write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body.

Comment: please edit your post and remove unused details and text to simplify your question and pay attention to focus on your main problem and explain more about it to help others answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all the references in models and also allowed for Sequelize to create the foreignkey fields by itself.

Those changes made the trick:

```js
const {DataTypes, Model} = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../config/connection');

class Message extends Model {
}

Message.init(
    {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false,
        },
        title: {type: DataTypes.STRING},
        content: {type: DataTypes.STRING},
        //user_id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false},
        // user_id: {type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false, references: {model: sequelize.models.User, key:"user_id"}},
    },
    {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'Message',
        freezeTableName: true,
        underscored: true,
        timestamps: true,
    }
);

module.exports = Message;
```

The models/index.js :

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const User = require('./User')
const Message = require('./Message')
const Comment = require('./Comment')


User.hasMany(Message, {foreignKey: {name: 'user_id', allowNull: false,}});
Message.belongsTo(User);

Message.hasMany(Comment, {foreignKey: {name: 'message_id', allowNull: false,}});
Comment.belongsTo(Message);

User.hasMany(Comment, {foreignKey: {name: 'user_id', allowNull: false,}});
Comment.belongsTo(User);

module.exports = {User, Message, Comment}
```